# Text cursor doesn't stop moving when I let go after holding the arrow keys

Tags: keyboard

My computer is a HP ENVY 17-cr0008ca, it's installed with linux with Pop OS. The problem I have is when I hold down the arrow key to move the text cursor left and right it doesn't stop for a few seconds after I let go and goes too far. I can't control how far it moves, it's really annoying. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a really funky hardware quirk to me!

Comment: It seems the problem is not the key and not the process, but the user: *What* do you try to achieve when holding down the cursor key? When in an editor there are better commands to go to the end of a word, line, paragraph, etc. The problem you describe was quite common for slow hardware using serial terminals in the 80ies, but the solution hasn't changed since then ;-)